# Returning nested structures from spider

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to work out how to get scrapy to return a nested data structure, as the only examples I can find deal with flat structures.

I am trying to scrape a forum, which is comprised of a list of threads, with each thread having a list of posts.

I can successfully scrape the list of threads, and the list of posts, but I am not sure how to get all the posts attached to the thread, instead of all jumbled together.

In the end, I am aiming for output like this:

```
<thread id="1">
    <post>Post 1</post>
    <post>Post 2</post>
</thread>
<thread id="2">
    <post>Post A</post>
    <post>Post B</post>
</thread>
```

If I do something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # For each thread on this page
    yield scrapy.Request(thread_url, self.parse_posts)

def parse_posts(self, response):
    # For each post on this page
    yield {'content': ... }
```

Then I just get a list of all posts without them being arranged into threads.  Something like this doesn't work, of course:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # For each thread on this page
    yield {
        'id': ...,
        'posts': scrapy.Request(thread_url, self.parse_posts)
    }
```

So I am not sure how to get the "child" requests to go into the "parent" object.

Answer (score 1):

As far as getting the association, like JimmyZhang said, this is exactly what meta is for.  Parse an ID out of the thread list page before yielding a request, pass that thread ID into the request via the meta keyword, then access the ID when processing the post.

```
def parse(self, response):
    # For each thread on this page
    thread_id = sel.xpath('thread_id_getter_xpath').extract()
    yield scrapy.Request(thread_url, callback=self.parse_posts,
                         meta={'thread_id': thread_id})

def parse_posts(self, response):
    # For each post on this page
    thread_id = response.meta['thread_id'])
    yield {'thread_id': thread_id, 'content': ... }
```

At this point, the items are associated.  How you compile data into a hierarchical format is entirely up to you, and dependent on your needs.  You could, for instance, write a pipeline to compile it all in a dictionary and output it at the end of the crawl.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider)
    # Assume self.forum is an empty dict at initialization 
    self.forum.setdefault(item.thread_id, [])
    self.forum[item.thread_id].append(['post': item.post_id, 
                                       'content': item.content])

def close_spider(self, spider)
    # Do something with self.forum, like output it as XML or JSON
    # ... or just print it to the stdout.
    print self.forum
```

Or you could compile an XML tree incrementally saving. Or serialize each item into a JSON string and dump to a file line by line.  Or add items to a database as you go.  Or whatever else your needs dictate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata.

First:

```
yield : scrapy.Request(thread_url, self.parse_posts,'meta'={'thread_id' : id})
```

Second, define a thread item:

```
class thread_item(Item):
    thread_id = Field()
    posts = Field()
```

Third, fetch the thread_id in parse_posts:

```
thread_id = response.meta['thread_id']
# parse posts content, construct thread item
yield item
```

Fourth, write a pipeline, and output the thread item.

Comment: But how does this make the structure nested?  `'posts': scrapy.Request...` doesn't actually work, which is the problem.

Comment: I update my answer, you should custom your pipeline, to output nested format.

Comment: Thanks - although the real answer is then how to do this with a pipeline, because as far as I can tell, nobody has done it before, so I'm still not sure it's possible!